# Grouping non-parameters of a function as variables?

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to document my python code, and I've got a django function that just receives "request", but I'd like to document what's supposed to be in request.GET...
How could I have doxygen layout nicely my variables that are currently commented as:

```
#  GET parameters:
#  {
#    'tag_id'   : int      = Tag ID, used if no tag-name given
#    'tag_name' : string   = Tag name, used if no TagID given
#    'last_id'  : int      = id of last displayed photo (that's the oldest one displayed!!!), optional
#    'max_n'    : int      = max number of photos to return, optional - def. 10
#    'bigt'     : bool     = optional, if present then returns bigger thumbs (400x260) instead of 300x200
#    'newest_id': int      = newest photoID got, optional. If given call returns newer images only
#  }
```